# Blocking service callbacks

Tags: ros, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I have been doing experiments with ROS services and currently I have this:

```
"""services_node.py"""
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import rospy
from beginner_tutorials.srv import * 

def handle_action_1(request):
    print "doing action 1"
    time.sleep(2)
    return Action1Response()

def handle_action_2(request):
    print "doing action 2"
    return Action2Response()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node("services_node")
    action_1 = rospy.Service("action_1", Action1, handle_action_1)
    action_2 = rospy.Service("action_2", Action2, handle_action_2)
    rospy.spin()


"""caller_1.py"""
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from beginner_tutorials.srv import *

rospy.wait_for_service("action_2")
action_2 = rospy.ServiceProxy('action_2', Action2)
i = 0
while True:
    print "take %d" % i
    print "calling for action_2" 
    action_2()
    i = i + 1

"""caller_2.py"""
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from beginner_tutorials.srv import *

rospy.wait_for_service("action_1")
action_1 = rospy.ServiceProxy('action_1', Action1)
i = 0
while True:
    print "take %d" % i
    print "calling for action_1" 
    action_1()
    i = i + 1
```

This nodes are basically a node that publishes two services, called "action_1" and "action_2", and two nodes that constantly call those services. By the way, the Action1 and Action2 services are empty services, with just a "---" in the .srv files.

The problem I see is that when I run these nodes, the caller_1 node shows the "calling for action_1" every two seconds, which makes sense for me. But, as far as I know, I would expect the caller_2 node to print its text every two seconds, since the services_node is "busy" with the callback for action_1. But what I see is that the caller_2 node works as if was alone, without waiting for the response.

Can you explain this please? I thought service callbacks were blocking, since it's just one node who is answering those services, but it seems the callbacks are not blocking in this case.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156721/blocking-service-callbacks/) by [crpizarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9346/crpizarr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-04-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Service calls are blocking in the sense that the caller will block until the server returns a response, and that the server for a particular service will only handle one request at a time.

I don't believe there's anything in the specification that says that two different services advertised from the same node will block each other. In reality, I suspect that rospy handles each service in its own thread, so that they don't block each other.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crpizarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9346/crpizarr/) on 2014-04-23**:
Given that, is there a way to make a service callback block other service callbacks? I ask because in the real project (not these dummy nodes) all the callbacks have to write in a TCP connection, so I need to make the callbacks exclusive in respect to each other. I know there are synchonization primitves as mutexes and stuff, but I would want to know if ROS has another way to do that.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-23**:
If you're trying to control access to a raw object, you should use the python synchronization primitives.